# windows 10 files disapearing with dual boot ubuntu 22.04 LTS OS short on space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery, data-loss

I have:

- 512GB SSD
- 8 GB RAM
- windows 10

  - 331 GB parition
- ubuntu 22.04 LTS

  - 4 GB swap area
  - 16 GB root partition
  - 121 GB home partition
- intel i5-8265U CPU
- no data backup

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/linuxforeveryone/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-and-dual-boot-alongside-windows-10-323a85271a73) but with the 22.04 LTS download, I'm still very new to Linux.

I either did something wrong or 16 GB isn't enough for the new OS. After a few days, after I had installed some programs Ubuntu started complaining it didn't have enough space for the OS. It still had a GB left so I ignored it at first, soon I noticed some files disappeared on windows. I stopped using Ubuntu. Windows forced an update. Nothing super important disappeared yet but it would be nice to get them back.

Questions:

- Why are files disappearing? Is windows deleting corrupted files?
- How do I stop more files from disappearing?
- How do I avoid making the problem worse?
- Can I retrieve the lost files?

Comment: The min for the root partition is 25 gig. Yes your root is way too small. With 22.04 using snaps the min should be more like 40 gig. There is no way Ubuntu is deleting files from Windows. Something else is going on. You appear to have multiple problems. Lost files are gone.

Comment: The recommended minimum is 25GB for a reason (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) though many 3rd party bloggers suggest less, as many users don't keep their system but '*distro hop*' rather quickly intending only to experiment (*why 8.6GB was included; ie. for those who won't install any additional apps*). Your expected usage will dictate what is required; but for me I need 27GB minimum (prefer 32GB). Either way running out of space would not cause files to *disappear*.. To have files erased requires user mistake or interaction (or shared data incorrectly setup)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: I'll try to increase the size of the root partition to 40 GB.

Comment: There definitely wasn't any user interaction, but there is a good chance I setup the shared data incorrectly. I was able to read (but not write) to the Windows files from  Linux, but Windows seemed unaware Linux existed. Is that normal?

Comment: @guiverc I'm not sure that question is relevant because the windows files not the Linux files disappeared, but I'll give it a try when the other problems are resolved.

Comment: Windows does not know about Ubuntu and you do not want it to to avoid issues. If you force write into hibernated NTFS, then Windows restores hibernated system & anything from Linux is gone. Fast start up is a Windows setting for hibernation & Windows updates turn it back on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I've disabled fast start up now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the problem really was or what I did but the issue seems to be solved.

Here are some things I tried:

1. Avoiding using Linux.
2. Resizing the root partition.
3. Looking the the Linux trashcan for files that disappeared on Windows.
4. Disabling fast start up